# Invalid API Key for package = Status code received = 12

Tags: android, google-maps

I have two separate Google API keys and in both I have added my same project as I wanted to build my app with new API key (paid) version. I am getting above error whenever I am running my android application

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid API Key for package = com.myproject. Status code received = 12
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1621)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1574)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaz.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzax.zzahp(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbb.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Did you get an answer for this ? We are getting the same on our Live App suddenly

Comment: We get the same in a strange pattern - it happens for a few users for a few days, then goes away. Then comes back after a week...

Comment: It seems the account paid doesnt support this API. Also Google Paid account has different subscription. So the one we had did not support. Created a separate project and did everything again and it worked. Also update your support libraries to the latest versions.